# executeQueryAsync don't behave as synchronously

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, jquery, jsom

I am creating different forms where I need same functions, so I created separate js file which I call on my each forms.

In below code if alert currentUser from success method then I get the value but If I call currentUser value from my forms in document ready then it will give me "**undefined**" how can I solve it.

```
var currentUser;

    $.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js", function () {
        $.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.js", execOperation);
    });
function execOperation() {
    // get context and then username
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();

    getUserName();
}
function getUserName() {
    user = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    currentUser = user.get_loginName();
}
function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
function getJSON(url) {
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url;

    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            return data.d;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed to get " + url);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the way I call from another page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert(currentUser);
    });
```

Comment: Where are you calling the getCurrentUser() from? I don't see you calling it. When you debug in developer tools, can you stop on the line: context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); and see if SP is loaded? Seems like you're using the SP without it being loaded first.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. I edited my code. But Still it is not working

Comment: did you stop the debugger at the line I told you about? was the SP object undefined at that time?

Comment: As I told you I am getting value when I calling from success method, but not getting when I call it from another page. That means it is loading SP object

Comment: add ``console.log( xyz )`` statements to all functions and you will see when what is executed. *note: your use of global variables inside functions is also something you should fix*

Comment: What i found @DannyEngelman is my another page is getting run first then execOperation, then getUserName and then Sucess function. due to that it is getting **undefiened**. But still I don't know how to make my variable come after sucess

Comment: So, you have to do your stuff in the success function.. currentuser is not undefined there.

Comment: @DannyEngelman I was seaching on the internet and I can see something to do with **deferred** But all things I am getting is not showing loading sp.js.

Comment: @Milind, the thing is, youare returning the username before the method executes, as it's an asynchronous operation. You would need to use Deferred objects in order to wait for the process to be completed to get your data.

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli Thank you for explanation. Can you give me example with reference to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you would need to structure your code in a way to get the result of the asynchronous operation, your code should be something like this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getUserName);

var user ;  //declare this as a variable related to your current namespace, only here for demonstration.

function getUserName(){
  var userPromise = retrieveUserCall();
  userPromise    //this line will wait until the server call completes
  .done(function(){
    //do something with user variable
  })
  .fail(function(){
    //do something on fail
  })
}

function retrieveUserCall(){
  var context = new SP.ClientContext();
  var web = context.get_web();
  user = web.get_currentUser();
  context.load(user);
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
      dfd.resolve();
    },
    function(){
      dfd.reject();
    });
  return dfd;   //dfd will return the result of the server call
}
```

Note that each call to the server is an asynchornous call, you don't know the result of it right away, and JavaScript will continue executing. So you need to declare a $.Deferred() variable that will store the result of the server call, and you would wait for the execution to complete with `.done()` for success and `.fail()` for fail.

Comment: strictly speaking ``userPromise`` will not 'wait' (**as in execution stops there**) Any code after it (in this case none) will execute. userPromise will 'listen' for an answer, then execute the chained done/fail/always etc. methods.

Comment: Hi Thanx for the reply with answer as this line is not loading SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getUserName); I am using this $.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js", function () {
        $.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.js", execOperation);
    }); That is main reason all mess is happening. Any solution for it

Comment: Well, jQuery and sharePoint are not a happy marriage... so use $.getScript only if you know what you are doing.. start learning at: http://www.spcaf.com/blog/sharepoint-javascript-context-dev-part-1/

Comment: @DannyEngelman userPromise code won't get executed until the return dfd is back with either resolve or reject, that's the whole purpose of promises..

Comment: any code **after** ``userPromise``, I was not referring to the promise chain.

Comment: That's why all of the logic is included within the promise done, fail. there's nothing after it ;)

Comment: @Milind I am confused, you said your problem is not with loading the SP and that it was already loaded in the success function, but you get back **undefined** please explain more what's going on so we can help you.

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli Superb Explanation !! Appreciated.